# Open Source Java Text Parsers

Tags: java, pdf, ms-office, openoffice.org, text-parsing

Is there a **single** Java text parser which can be used to parse Office (windows) documents, OpenOffice documents, and PDFs as well? Else do I need to use something like Apache POI for Word documents and other libraries for OpenOffice and PDFs? If so what are the best options for OpenOffice and PDFs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/):

> The Apache Tika™ toolkit detects and
>   extracts metadata and structured text
>   content from various documents using
>   existing parser libraries.

Not sure whether this qualifies as "single" for your purposes.

Comment: what does extracting metadata mean? Is this the same as extracting the body of text from a document?other than that, this looks fine.

Comment: +1. I used it. It pretty much seems to do the job. Slight downside is that since it is using many existing libraries, a bunch of jars are needed.

Answer (score 2):

If the task is reading PDF documents, [iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php) is your best bet. 
For Microsoft Office and OpenOffice (LibreOffice) based documents, POI would be my solution.

Comment: its free in terms that you should release the source of the application which uses the itex api. quip from the site..

"Buying such a license is mandatory as soon as you develop commercial activities involving the iText software without disclosing the source code of your own applications. "

http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php

Comment: POI can't read OpenOffice (LibreOffice) based documents, AFAIK.  PDF Box is an Apache alternative which can read PDF documents.